# Auto Logout in Codeigniter 4 randomly

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, session-cookies, codeigniter-4

I am facing random logout in my ci 4 application. It's like just login and click a menu and auto logout (back to login page) and sometimes i can click 2 until 3 menus and then directly logout again.

In my localhost is fine but after i deployed in server, this issue happens.

I am using DatabaseHandler as Session Driver and my sessionExpiration is 7200

Comment: which version of CI 4 are you using?

Comment: @Vickel i am using 4.1.9

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest 4.2.8, there have been a lot of bug fixes and some changes since 4.1.9, see [Change Logs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/changelogs/index.html)

Comment: @Vickel okay i will update it, thanks

Comment: please give some feedback, if it worked

Comment: @Vickel, i will give feedback once i update my ci 4 version

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this issue because of public $sessionMatchIP = true;

In my localhost, this issue won't happens because ip_address always same (::1). But when user access the application via internet, public ip always changed. That's why session destroyed randomly

Comment: This is not actually true. A dynamic IP address may change periodically but generally not within 7200 second window. I suspect there is something else at play here. I experienced problems with CI4 sessions where `now()` is used in the DB handler which I manually override in the system files. I think you might find its something else.

Comment: @Antony Could you please describe more your root cause? and how you override it? so it means this issue from ci 4 bug?